# Can't automatically sort buttons alphabetically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, button

I'm currently having some trouble automatically sorting buttons alphabetically. I can't figure out how to sort these buttons (jquery/javascript), but I want to do it **automatically, when the page loads.** Thanks for the help. Here's my code:

```
<style>
.games-button {
  background-color: #383838;
  color: #eeeeee;
  text-align: middle;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 14px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 5px;
  height:42px;
  vertical-align: left;
  display: inline-block;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
  float: left;
  overflow:hidden;
  margin-left:100px;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  text-transform: uppercase;

}
.games-button:hover {
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 100px 100px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
}

</style>

<button class="games-button" style="width:240px;" onclick="window.open('/samplepage.html','_blank');">A</button>
<button class="games-button" style="width:240px;" onclick="window.open('/samplepage.html','_blank');">Z</button>
<button class="games-button" style="width:240px;" onclick="window.open('/samplepage.html','_blank');">H</button>
<button class="games-button" style="width:240px;" onclick="window.open('/samplepage.html','_blank');">B</button>
<button class="games-button" style="width:240px;" onclick="window.open('/samplepage.html','_blank');">N</button>
<button class="games-button" style="width:240px;" onclick="window.open('/samplepage.html','_blank');">C</button>
```

Update:
This is a code I have that sorts the buttons on click of a button. How can I do this without a button?

```
<button onclick="sortList()">Sort</button>

<ul id="id01">
  <button>z</button>
 <button>a</button> 
 <button>b</button>
 <button>l</button>
 <button>b</button>

</ul>

<script>
function sortList() {
  var list, i, switching, b, shouldSwitch;
  list = document.getElementById("id01");
  switching = true;
  while (switching) {
    switching = false;
    b = list.getElementsByTagName("button");
    for (i = 0; i < (b.length - 1); i++) {
      shouldSwitch = false;
      if (b[i].innerHTML.toLowerCase() > b[i + 1].innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {
        shouldSwitch = true;
        break;
      }
    }
    if (shouldSwitch) {
      b[i].parentNode.insertBefore(b[i + 1], b[i]);
      switching = true;
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: What generates the buttons that means they aren't placed in the correct order?

Comment: Well even if the buttons aren't place in correct order, I wanted them sorted. I can sort the buttons, but it would take a really long time because I'm going to have a lot of buttons

Comment: Where's the code where you're actually trying to sort the buttons?

Comment: where did you find that code?
Probably that button is tied to an eventListener that executes a function which results in having the buttons sorted. Simply take that function code out of the eventListener.

Comment: @JorgeSolis I got a code that switches the buttons now, with a click of a button. I just don't know how to do this with automatically without pressing a button.

Comment: Nope, that code wouldn't work. 'document.getElementById("id01");' would throw an error since that element doesn't exist

Comment: @JorgeSolis Somehow, this code actually works. When you press the button, javascript sorts the buttons. It works perfectly, it's just how to do I fake an onclick with out even clicking the button? (In other words, how to I make this script to work when I press no button.) Thanks

Comment: I didn't read the html part of the update lol. I'm writing a proper answer.

Comment: So instead of the button `onclick` event you need [window.onload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you're getting into js development. Good luck with that.

In order to manipulate DOM elements, it's always easier if you put in some trails or hints to help your code find your elements.

In this case, all of your buttons are placed in the body element, so to make it easier to locate and replace the buttons, place them inside another element. Like so:

```
<div id="button-container">
  <button class="games-button" style="width:240px;" onclick="window.open('/samplepage.html','_blank');">A</button>
  <button class="games-button" style="width:240px;" onclick="window.open('/samplepage.html','_blank');">Z</button>
  <button class="games-button" style="width:240px;" onclick="window.open('/samplepage.html','_blank');">H</button>
  <button class="games-button" style="width:240px;" onclick="window.open('/samplepage.html','_blank');">B</button>
  <button class="games-button" style="width:240px;" onclick="window.open('/samplepage.html','_blank');">N</button>
  <button class="games-button" style="width:240px;" onclick="window.open('/samplepage.html','_blank');">C</button>
</div>
```

Then locate them and sort them.

```
<script>
  'use strict';
  const buttonContainer = document.getElementById('button-container');
  const sortedButtons = [... buttonContainer.children].sort((buttonA, buttonB) => {
    const name1 = buttonA.innerText.toLowerCase();
    const name2 = buttonB.innerText.toLowerCase();
    if(name1 === name2){
      return 0;
    } else if(name1 < name2){
      return -1;
    } else {
      return 0;
    }
  });
  sortedButtons.forEach(button => buttonContainer.append(button));
</script>
```

That's it.

Comment: I took some extra steps so it was easier to understand. Hope it helps

Comment: Your question is not understandable, please edit to see what you want