# Button Elements not sorting in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, sorting

I am currently having some trouble with automatically sorting some buttons by their value in Firefox. This works in Chrome but I'm not sure why it's not working in Firefox. My goal is to have this work for either browser. Any help would be appreciated.

And the code that works in Chrome found from [this StackOverflow question:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60645925/cant-automatically-sort-buttons-alphabetically)

```js
// Sort Buttons based on their Values.
const buttonContainer = $("#B1CSTButtonContainer")[0];
const sortedButtons = [...buttonContainer.children].sort((buttonA, buttonB) => {
  const value1 = buttonA.value;
  const value2 = buttonB.value;
  if (value1 === value2) {
    return 0;
  } else if (value1 < value2) {
    return -1;
  } else {
    return 0;
  }
});
sortedButtons.forEach(button => buttonContainer.append(button));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="B1CSTButtonContainer" style="border: 2px solid grey; border-radius: 5px; display: inline-block; padding: 2px; width: 100%;">
  <button id="B1CSTERButton"   value="11" style="float: left; margin: 2px;">ER</button>
  <button id="B1CSTCMButton"   value="06" style="float: left; margin: 2px;">CM</button>
  <button id="B1CSTITMAButton" value="08" style="float: left; margin: 2px;">ITMA</button>
  <button id="B1CST3DARButton" value="09" style="float: left; margin: 2px;">3DAR</button>
  <button id="B1CST7DARButton" value="10" style="float: left; margin: 2px;">7DAR</button>
  <button id="B1CSTPRButton"   value="05" style="float: left; margin: 2px;">PR</button>
  <button id="B1CSTPSButton"   value="04" style="float: left; margin: 2px;">PS</button>
  <button id="B1CSTPSOAButton" value="07" style="float: left; margin: 2px;">PSOA</button>
  <button id="B1CSTPTButton"   value="03" style="float: left; margin: 2px;">PT</button>
  <button id="B1CSTECDButton"  value="12" style="float: left; margin: 2px;">ECD</button>
  <button id="B1CSTRESButton"      value="02" style="float: left; margin: 2px;">RES</button>
  <button id="B1CSTWIPButton"      value="01" style="float: left; margin: 2px;">WIP</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Your question is not understandable, please edit to see what you want

Comment: You're comparing the values as strings, not numbers. So `value="100"` will sort before `value="99"`

Comment: The function that adds those buttons, has the Settings & Help button being appended after `sortedButtons.forEach(button => buttonContainer.append(button));` is executed so they're always last.

Comment: You return zero if equal. You return zero if greater than. Do you see your logic problem?

Comment: The second `return 0;` should be `return 1;`. I'm guessing this was just a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply use `.appendChild()` method
( and some css too to be readable )

```js
// Sort Buttons based on their Values --- :
const buttonContainer = document.querySelector('#B1CSTButtonContainer');
  
[...buttonContainer.querySelectorAll('button')]
  .map(btn=>({btn, val: +btn.value }))
  .sort((a,b) => a.val - b.val)
  .forEach( elm => buttonContainer.appendChild(elm.btn) )

// -*-*-
```

```css
#B1CSTButtonContainer {
  border        : 2px solid grey;
  border-radius : 5px;
  display       : inline-block; 
  padding       : 2px;
  width         : 100%;
  }
#B1CSTButtonContainer > button {
  float  : left; 
  margin : 2px;
  }
```

```html
<div id="B1CSTButtonContainer">
  <button id="B1CSTERButton"       value="11"  > ER   </button>
  <button id="B1CSTCMButton"       value="06"  > CM   </button>
  <button id="B1CSTITMAButton"     value="08"  > ITMA </button>
  <button id="B1CST3DARButton"     value="09"  > 3DAR </button>
  <button id="B1CST7DARButton"     value="10"  > 7DAR </button>
  <button id="B1CSTPRButton"       value="05"  > PR   </button>
  <button id="B1CSTPSButton"       value="04"  > PS   </button>
  <button id="B1CSTPSOAButton"     value="07"  > PSOA </button>
  <button id="B1CSTPTButton"       value="03"  > PT   </button>
  <button id="B1CSTECDButton"      value="12"  > ECD  </button>
  <button id="B1CSTRESButton"      value="02"  > RES  </button>
  <button id="B1CSTWIPButton"      value="01"  > WIP  </button>
  <button id="B1CSTSettingsButton" value="100" > ⚙    </button>
  <button id="B1CSTHelpButton"     value="99"  > ❓   </button>
</div>
```